# How to iterate backwards through an array?

Tags: arrays, string, for-loop, iterator, iteration

I want to take each value from the end of the array and iterate backwards to the middle of the array, adding each value to a string:

```
  for (int x = testArray.length - 1; x > testArray.length/2; x--){
     b+=testArray[x];
  }
```

It doesn't seem to work because when I print b it is an empty space. Is it possible to iterate backwards through an array and add the values to a string. They are all String values.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that if the array's length is an odd number, then your code wont work, since the length divided by 2 would be a decimal. Convert the middle index to an `int`. You should be using `StringBuilder` too if you're using quite a bit of concatenations.

```
String[] names = {", and Henry, ", ", David", "Bob"};
StringBuilder allNames = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = names.length - 1; i >= (int) names.length/2; i--)
{
    allNames.append(names[i]);
}

System.out.println(allNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String b = "";    
for (int x = testArray.length - 1; x > testArray.length/2; x--){
     b+=testArray[x];
}
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: While this seems to answer the question, It'd be better to explain with words what's happening here